# Best way to reject some elements from array

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$array = array(
   'aaaDSgsdfg' => 3,
   'aaaRewrwer' => 4,
   'bbbBsdfs' => 1,
   'aaaGgfdg' => 4,
   'bbbTrtert' => 5
);
```

Which is the best way to reject element with index starting with "bbb"?

I can:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $index => $element) {
   if (substr($index, 0, 2) == 'aaa') {
       $new[$index] = $element;
   }
}
```

But maybe is better function for this? Maybe array_map?

Comment: Please think how long this string will be: `substr($index, 0, 2)` you probably want to change the length to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_filter is what you are looking for:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($key) {
   return substr($index, 0, 2) === 'aaa';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP 5.6+, you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to achieve this:

```
$array = array_filter(
  $array,
  function ($e) { return strpos($e, 'bbb') !== 0; },
  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

See https://eval.in/669810

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($index) {
    return substr($index, 0, 2) === 'aaa'
})
```